# How To Record Audio In React Native iOS?

Tags: react-native, audio-recording

**Error Occurred During Initiating Recorder - iOS 16.0 - iPhone 14 Pro Simulator**

Version of react-native-audio-recorder-player
3.5.3

Version of React Native
0.71.4

Platforms You Faced The Error (IOS or Android or Both?)
Android Works Perfectly (Real Device & Emulator)
iOS Doesn't Work (Real Device & Simulator)

Expected Behavior
Start Recording

Actual Behavior
Not Initializing Recording

Some Code Example

```
const path = Platform.select({
ios: ${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.CacheDir}/sound.m4a,
android: ${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.CacheDir}/sound.mp4,
});
```

```
const onStartRecording = React.useCallback(async () => {
setIsRecording(true);
await audioRecorderPlayer.startRecorder(path);
audioRecorderPlayer.addRecordBackListener(e => {
setRecordingTime(
audioRecorderPlayer.mmssss(Math.floor(e.currentPosition)).split(':')[0] + ':' +
audioRecorderPlayer.mmssss(Math.floor(e.currentPosition)).split(':')[1],
);
});
}, []);
```

```
const onStopRecording = React.useCallback(async () => {
setIsRecording(false);
await audioRecorderPlayer.stopRecorder();
audioRecorderPlayer.removeRecordBackListener();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to ask microphone permission.

**Info.plist**

```
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) need access to Microphone</string>
```

You need to pass audioSet config for it to work on both platforms. Since ios audio quality differs from android.

**Code**

```
const onStartRecording = React.useCallback(async () => {
  setIsRecording(true);
  const fileName = `recording${Date.now()}`;

  const path = Platform.select({
     ios: `${fileName}.aac`,
     android: `${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.CacheDir}/${fileName}.m4a`, //don't use mp4, it'll increase app size
  });

  const audioSet = {
     AudioEncoderAndroid: AudioEncoderAndroidType.AAC,
     AudioSourceAndroid: AudioSourceAndroidType.MIC,
     AVEncoderAudioQualityKeyIOS: AVEncoderAudioQualityIOSType.high,
     AVNumberOfChannelsKeyIOS: 2,
     AVFormatIDKeyIOS: AVEncodingOption.aac,
     AVModeIOS: AVModeIOSOption.videochat,
  };

     await audioRecorderPlayer.startRecorder(path, audioSet);
     audioRecorderPlayer.addRecordBackListener(e => {
     setRecordTime(
     audioRecorderPlayer.mmssss(Math.floor(e.currentPosition)).split(':')[0] + ':' +
     audioRecorderPlayer.mmssss(Math.floor(e.currentPosition)).split(':')[1],
  )})
}, []);
```

```
const onStopRecording = React.useCallback(async () => {
  setIsRecording(false);
  await audioRecorderPlayer.stopRecorder();
  audioRecorderPlayer.removeRecordBackListener();
}, []);
```